# Paragraph is overlapping outside my div on hover

Tags: html, css

and I'm trying to add a black container below my video and add the title and description inside that black container on hover, but the description in overlapping the black container how to l keep it inside the black container.

```css
.previewContainer.small {
  position: relative;
  width: 230px;
  height: 129px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  display: inline-flex;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  transition: transform 500ms;
}

.title{
  display: none;
}

.previewContainer.small:focus-within,
.previewContainer.small:hover{
  margin-left: 65px;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
  width: 230px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #141414;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.small:focus ~ .small,
.small:hover ~ .small {
  transform: translateX(25%);
}

.previewContainer.small:focus,
.previewContainer.small:hover {
  transform: scale(1.6);
  z-index: 1;
}

.Play{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

.title{
  position: absolute;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 5px;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

.description{
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration:none;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
}

.title h6{
  color:#fff !important;
  font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.video-item {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="previewContainer">
          <div class="previewContainer small">
            <a href"">
              <video class="mylist-img video-item" onmouseover="this.play()" onmouseout="this.pause();">
                <source src="https://sgcholdings.co.za/Backend/media/sample-30s.mp4">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
              </video>
              <div class="title">
                <h6>Video One</h6>
              </div>
              <div class="description">
                <p class="">Loren ipsum dolor sit amet because there are two,
                  there is web version which works on hover with a small pop up then </p>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

so l want to contain the description to be inside that black background that comes when l hover. can someone assist how to contain the paragraph tag not to overlap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your CSS with following code

```
.description {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

`white-space:normal` Sequences of white space are collapsed. Newline characters in the source are handled the same as other white space. Lines are broken as necessary to fill line boxes.

Comment: It may be worth noting that you are having to do that because an ancestor element (previewontainer small) has white-space: nowrap set.

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS for div of class description add this rule

```
.description{
 word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

CSS word-wrap property is used to break the long words and wrap them onto the next line. This property is used to prevent overflow when an unbreakable string is too long to fit in the containing box.

```css
.previewContainer.small {
  position: relative;
  width: 230px;
  height: 129px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  display: inline-flex;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  transition: transform 500ms;
}

.title{
  display: none;
}

.previewContainer.small:focus-within,
.previewContainer.small:hover{
  margin-left: 65px;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
  width: 230px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #141414;
  border-radius: 5px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.small:focus ~ .small,
.small:hover ~ .small {
  transform: translateX(25%);
}

.previewContainer.small:focus,
.previewContainer.small:hover {
  transform: scale(1.6);
  z-index: 1;
}

.Play{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

.title{
  position: absolute;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 5px;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

.description{
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration:none;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}

.title h6{
  color:#fff !important;
  font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.video-item {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="previewContainer">
          <div class="previewContainer small">
            <a href"">
              <video class="mylist-img video-item" onmouseover="this.play()" onmouseout="this.pause();">
                <source src="https://sgcholdings.co.za/Backend/media/sample-30s.mp4">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
              </video>
              <div class="title">
                <h6>Video One</h6>
              </div>
              <div class="description">
                <p class="">Loren ipsum dolor sit amet because there are two,
                  there is web version which works on hover with a small pop up then </p>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Mohit, in my case this solution failed, but l appreciate it

Comment: This setting is to tell the system to break any very long words that won't fit. You may want to consider doing that too in case  your 'small' preview container is really small.

Comment: @MrRobot it was not working because in the .previewContainer.small class you had white-space: nowarp without any reason, now see this code it is working with word-wrap which is the right way of doing this implementation, but the guy who answered above just overridden the rule of white space.